# What is the correct way to connect inports to a subsystem in Matlab/Simulink? I'm getting Invalid Simulink object name

Tags: matlab, port, simulink, subsystem

I'm working with a model in Simulink, that contains a lots of inports and outports, and a subsystem. I'm trying to connect them programmatically because it is a really huge model.

I've tried getting the handles of the ports, using the name of the ports, and I'm still getting errors like "Invalid Simulink object name" or "Invalid Simulink port handle"

The following code will create a minimum subsystem, I would like to recall that in the real system I'm working there could be 50+ ports, and them does not necessarily connect "one by one", I mean, sometimes the first inport will be connected to the third inport from the subsystem, for example.

```
% Creating little subsystem and inports
open_system(new_system('my_system'));
add_block('simulink/Commonly Used Blocks/In1', 'my_system/port_name_1');
add_block('simulink/Commonly Used Blocks/In1', 'my_system/port_name_2');
add_block('built-in/Subsystem', 'my_system/test_subsystem');
add_block('simulink/Commonly Used Blocks/In1', 'my_system/test_subsystem/test_name_1');
add_block('simulink/Commonly Used Blocks/In1', 'my_system/test_subsystem/test_name_2');
```

[image: Model with inports and subsystem]

Here is where I get some of the error messages:

```
add_line('my_system', 'my_system/port_name_1', 'my_system/test_subsystem/test_name_1', 'autorouting', 'smart');

% Error: Invalid Simulink object name: my_system/port_name_1
```

```
porthandle = get_param('my_system/port_name_1', 'Handle');
subsystem_port_handle = get_param('my_system/test_subsystem/test_name_1', 'Handle');
add_line('my_system', porthandle, subsystem_port_handle, 'autorouting', 'smart');

% Error: Invalid Simulink port handle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the doc for [add_block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html), the correct syntax in each case is

```
add_line('my_system', 'port_name_1/1', 'test_subsystem/1', 'autorouting', 'smart');
```

and

```
porthandle = get_param('my_system/port_name_1', 'PortHandles');
subsystem_port_handle = get_param('my_system/test_subsystem', 'PortHandles');
add_line('my_system', porthandle.Outport(1), subsystem_port_handle.Inport(1), 'autorouting', 'smart');
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Phil Goddard. Is there any consideration if instead connecting from inports to subsystem I try to connect subsystem to outports?

Comment: Connecting ports uses the above syntax irrespective of what types of blocks are being connected, it's just the name and port number that changes.